# How to Insert one to many relationship using checkboxlist in VB.NET, LINQ to SQL?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql, one-to-many, checkboxlist

I have 3 tables:

> **CustomerType**
>  CusID
>
> **EventType**
>  EventTypeID
>
> **CustomerEventType**
>  CusID 
> EventTypeID

How to Insert one to many relationship using checkboxlist in VB.NET, LINQ to SQL?

```
dim newEventType = new EventType
newEventType.EventID = 1
db.EventType.InsertOnSubmit(newEventType)
db.submitchange()
```

Then I want it to automatically insert data into `CustomerEventType` table based on the last EvenTypeID data that's just inserted and the checks of the CusID that is using `CheckBoxList1` bounded from `CustomerType` (Suppose there are 2 IDs).

After I click on Insert button the data in EventType table and CustomerEventType table should be:

> **EventType**  
>  EventTypeID
>  1
>   **CustomerEventType**
>  EventTypeID.....CusID
>   1........................1
>   1........................2

The only question that I have is, what should be the code behind the insert button using VB.NET LINQ-to-SQL to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a custom class CustomerEventType containing EventTypeID and CusID. Then create a collection of CustomerEventType and pass that to a sub routine or function that will loop through and insert each CustomerEventType using linq.